# take a list and subtract every number of that list, with its next number in Racket

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

Given a list of any length in Racket create a new list from the absolute values of the differences of successive elements. The last element of the new list should be the absolute value of the difference between the first element and the last element of the input list.

For Example: an input t = (2, 6, 7, 11) should result in t' = (4, 1, 4, 9).

Here is what I have:

```
(define (a-succ t i)
  (cond [(empty? t) empty]
        [(>= i (size t)) t]
        [else
         (cons (abs (- (first t)
                       (first (rest t))))
               (a-succ (rest t) i))]))
```

The problem is that by that approach I can't subtract the first number of the list with the last number because the first number changes after running the program. So I think the first step that needs to be done is to subtract the first number with the reversed first number, by defining a new function. I just can't figure out how to change the list once and then apply my recursion function with the changed list.

Comment: What should a list of length 1 produce? Is this a homework exercise, and are there any constraints on your solution? Does your solution have to use recursion? "_I have tried a lot of things...I just cant find a good approach..._": show your best effort; what isn't working?

Comment: A list of legth 1 should give (list 0). Its a homework exercise that was designed to be solved by recursion. Down below is the code i have got so far.

Comment: What is the purpose of `i` in the posted code? There is no mention of this in the problem description. It would be helpful if you showed an example function call and the expected result (instead of showing an abstract transformation on a comma-separated list). Also, what is `size`? Did you mean `length`, or are you using `#lang racket`, or some other student language?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear why you need the parameter `i` in the posted code. Also, note that the base case `(empty? t)` is never reached, because  `(>= i (size t))` is always reached first.

The way the I usually solve the problem of needing to modify an input list inside a procedure before processing it is to use a [named `let`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html?q=size#%28part._.Named_let%29):

```
(define (pairwise-diff xs)
  (let loop ((cycle (append xs (list (first xs)))))
    (if (< (length cycle) 2)
        '()
        (cons (abs (- (first cycle) (second cycle)))
              (loop (rest cycle))))))
```

Here, the modified input list (with the first element added to the end of the list) is bound to `cycle` in the body of `loop`. An empty input list will result in a `cycle` of length 1, and all other input lists will result in a `cycle` of length 2 or greater, so the base case is when `cycle` is less than 2. When `cycle` is less than 2, there are no subtractions to be done and the empty list should be returned. Otherwise, the result of processing the first two items of `cycle` is `cons`ed onto the result of processing the rest of `cycle`.

You can accomplish the same thing by using `define` instead of named `let`:

```
(define (pairwise-diff xs)
  (define (helper cycle)
    (if (< (length cycle) 2)
        '()
        (cons (abs (- (first cycle) (second cycle)))
              (helper (rest cycle)))))
  (helper (append xs (list (first xs)))))
```

Here the `helper` function does the actual work, and `pairwise-diff` just calls `helper` with the modified input list.

Sample interaction:

```
scratch.rkt> (pairwise-diff '(2 6 7 11))
'(4 1 4 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to define a helper.  If that helper is a top-level function it needs to carry the first element of the list with it:

```
(define (a-succ l)
  (asl l (first l) '()))

(define (asl t f r)
  (if (empty? (rest t))
      (reverse (cons (abs (- f (first t))) r))
      (asl (rest t) f (cons (abs (- (first t) (second t))) r))))
```

But you can make it a local function which means it can rely on knowing the list its parent got:

```
(define (a-succ l)
  (define (asl t r)
    (if (empty? (rest t))
        (reverse (cons (abs (- (first l) (first t))) r))
        (asl (rest t) (cons (abs (- (first t) (second t))) r))))
  (asl l '()))
```